# Can't deploy Django on Heroku due to static error

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, heroku-cli

Hello I am trying to launch my django website on heroku. I downloaded the heroku CLI, and I am running the following code on fish to resolve the error:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

however I am getting the following error

```
     ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very clearly indicating you need to add `-a` or `--app` flag

Try running,

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 -a YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE
```